# Access is denied when creating virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, directoryentry

I got this error

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

when I try to create Virtual Directory using vb.net code with asp.net web forms and the following the code that I used ..

```
Private Sub CreateVirtualDir(ByVal WebSite As String, ByVal AppName As String, ByVal Path As String)

        Dim IISSchema As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://" & WebSite & "/Schema/AppIsolated")
        Dim CanCreate As Boolean = Not IISSchema.Properties("Syntax").Value.ToString.ToUpper() = "BOOLEAN"
        IISSchema.Dispose()

        If CanCreate Then
            Dim PathCreated As Boolean

            Try
                Dim IISAdmin As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("IIS://" & WebSite & "/W3SVC/1/Root")

                'make sure folder exists
                If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path)
                    PathCreated = True
                End If

                'If the virtual directory already exists then delete it
                For Each VD As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry In IISAdmin.Children
                    If VD.Name = AppName Then
                        IISAdmin.Invoke("Delete", New String() {VD.SchemaClassName, AppName})
                        IISAdmin.CommitChanges()
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next VD

                'Create and setup new virtual directory
                Dim VDir As System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = IISAdmin.Children.Add(AppName, "IIsWebVirtualDir")
                VDir.Properties("Path").Item(0) = Path
                VDir.Properties("AppFriendlyName").Item(0) = AppName
                VDir.Properties("EnableDirBrowsing").Item(0) = False
                VDir.Properties("AccessRead").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AccessExecute").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AccessWrite").Item(0) = False
                VDir.Properties("AccessScript").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AuthNTLM").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AuthBasic").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AspBufferingOn").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("EnableDefaultDoc").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("DefaultDoc").Item(0) = "default.htm,default.aspx,default.asp"
                VDir.Properties("AspEnableParentPaths").Item(0) = True
                VDir.Properties("AuthAnonymous").Item(0) = True
                VDir.CommitChanges()

                'the following are acceptable params
                'INPROC = 0
                'OUTPROC = 1
                'POOLED = 2
                VDir.Invoke("AppCreate", 1)

            Catch Ex As Exception
                If PathCreated Then
                    System.IO.Directory.Delete(Path)
                End If



            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

any help please >????

Comment: What user runs your code? Access denied is a security issue, meaning check external factors as well.

Comment: What do you mean about What user runs your code ? know could I now this user ?

Comment: Your code... all code... runs under the auspices of some specific user account, and has only the security authorizations afforded that account. I'm wondering whether it's running under a different user account than you expect.

Comment: I appropriated for your help but I still don't know how to get that user and give him the permissions .

Comment: Search for the identity of the application pool

Comment: how to set AppPool using the above code ?

Comment: Which line throws the error? Also, it is probably best to comment out the Try..Catch part while you are testing it so that you see all errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the application by visual studio, start visual studio as **Administrator**

If you are running by IIS, set your user as administrator **or** an user that have the required permissions on **Application Pool** 
Open IIS / go to Application Pools / right click your application pool / Advanced Settings / Process Model / Load User Profile = true/

click **Identity** and choose your account

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This Solution worked for me ==>

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/05/13/iis-7-adsi-error-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x80005000-unknown-error-0x80005000.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage ..

In Addition i did this also which resolved my issue ::

Issue i was getting ==>

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] {"Access is denied.\r\n"}     System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

ErrorCode 0x80070005
```

Solution which get my issue resolved :: After doing all above stated things in Link.

I have to do this also to resolve Access denied error ==> Run all Administrator in admin approval mode ==> Disabled ..